# Angular 17 hydration - AWS URL add twice on SSR to http response

Tags: angular, http, hydration, angular-ssr

I am trying API response transformation to add the AWS S3 bucket URL as a prefix to the banner URL from the API side. It works correctly without SSR. But when I tried with SSR it added URL prefix twice.

Without SSR

> https://shm-stg.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dshm-dev/65708131bbcf697cb1c3ac9b/hd/image/thumbnail_watermark/1.jpeg

With SSR

> https://shm-stg.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dshm-dev/https://shm-stg.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dshm-dev/65708131bbcf697cb1c3ac9b/hd/image/thumbnail_watermark/1.jpeg

Here is code for http response transformation

```
awsUrl = environment.awsUrl;

getEndpoint(): string {
  return API.COLLECTION_HEADING;
}

override get(params: Partial<EntityParams>): Observable<APIResponse<CollectionHeadingListModel[]>> {
  const httpParams = this.createHttpParamsFromPartial(params);
  return this.http.get<APIResponse<CollectionHeadingListModel[]>>(this.getEndpoint(), { params: httpParams }).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      res.data.forEach((heading) => heading.banner = `${this.awsUrl}${heading.banner}`);
    })
  );
}
```

**Its working fine if I remove** `provideClientHydration()` from `providers`

Any help on this will be really appriciated

Comment: please share the code for getEndpoint and if possible the method that contains the return!

Comment: @NarenMurali getEndpoint() will simply return the API URL. Also I have updated my question with more codes

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing the `tap` into `map`, since you are modifying the response but not returning.

```
awsUrl = environment.awsUrl;

getEndpoint(): string {
  return API.COLLECTION_HEADING;
}

override get(params: Partial<EntityParams>): Observable<APIResponse<CollectionHeadingListModel[]>> {
  const httpParams = this.createHttpParamsFromPartial(params);
  return this.http.get<APIResponse<CollectionHeadingListModel[]>>(this.getEndpoint(), { params: httpParams }).pipe(
    map(res => { // <-- changed here
      res.data.forEach((heading) => heading.banner = `${this.awsUrl}${heading.banner}`);
      return res; // <-- changed here
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: No, it's not working. Same issue. if I use the tap operator then also it works. The issue is only for SSR hydration